# Original name and extension of the image using Cropper.js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, cropperjs

I'm uploading my images with ajax, and using Cropper.js and laravel to upload them to the server.
How can I get the original name and extension of the file in the backend?

Result of `dd($request->file('my_image'))`

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#6538
  -test: false
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "php1EB0.tmp"
  basename: "php1EB0.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php1EB0.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php1EB0.tmp"
  aTime: 2023-09-15 09:43:22
  mTime: 2023-09-15 09:43:22
  cTime: 2023-09-15 09:43:22
  inode: 171136785840103944
  size: 53334
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php1EB0.tmp"
}
```